# how to associate view controller and xib file

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

When I create a uiviewcontroller from the "new file..." wizard with "create xib file" option, I can load it by just `SomeViewController *view = [[SomeViewController alloc] init]`. But when I rename the xib file name, this code stops working, even though the file owner in the xib is still the right view controller.

I found that I can only get the view up by calling `initWithNib`. I am just wondering what was linking the xib with the view controller behind the scene? Can I still use `init` to get the xib loaded after renaming the file?

Regards

Leo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can load it by just `SomeViewController *view = [[SomeViewController alloc] init]`.

You can, but (IMO) you shouldn't. The designated initializer for UIViewController is `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. You might implement an `-init` method in your own view controller that calls `[super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`, but I think the code is clearer if you stick with the same name.

Also, make sure you read the documentation for UIViewController, particularly the discussion, which says:

> If you specify nil for the nibName parameter, you must either override
>   the loadView method and create your views there or you must provide a
>   nib file in your bundle whose name (without the .nib extension)
>   matches the name of your view controller class.

This is why the view controller will load a .xib file that has the same name as the view controller's class (or the name returned by the `-nibName` method, as explaind a little further on in the docs).

In short, UIViewController is functioning exactly as documented.

Comment: Specifically from the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname?language=objc

`1. If the view controller class name ends with the word ‘Controller’, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the class name without the word ‘Controller’, as in MyView.nib.

2.It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.`